# Efficient representations of natural numbers via arithmetical expressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, peano-arithmetic, computational-complexity

A given natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ has many *representations*
as expressions mixing other natural numbers and the operators and punctuation symbols
$\{+,-,\times,/,\exp,(,)\}$, where '$\exp$' means exponentiation. For example,
four representations of $128$ are $\{130-2,128, 2 \times 64, 2^7\}$.
Define the *cost* of a representation as the total number of digits that occur in the
representation, with all operators and parentheses assigned zero cost.
In other words, imagine erasing all the symbols and just counting up the digits.
So the costs of the four representations of $128$ above are $\{4,3,3,2\}$.

I am interested in minimal-cost representations of numbers, and especially those numbers
that have representations of smaller cost than their explicit representation as just a number with no operators. In some sense, I am asking for which numbers are compressible via the operators. (Thinking about compression is the origin of this question.) Unfortunately, I think the notion is base-dependent, but perhaps not fundamentally so.

Here are two specific questions:

(1) Which natural numbers have a representation more efficient than the unadorned number? At least, what is the start of such a list? In particular, which is the smallest
number efficiently representable? (In base $10$; but other bases are equally
interesting.)
 
**Answered** by *Gerry Myerson*. The list starts
$5^3{=}125,\; 2^7{=}128,\; 6^3{=}216,\; 3^5{=}243,\; 4^4{=}256, \ldots$.

(2) What fraction of numbers $n \le N$ have a more efficient representation than
themselves, as $N \to \infty$? Perhaps this question has a base-independent answer?

Analogous questions may have been explored previously, perhaps with a different
set of operators. If so, I'd appreciate a pointer—Thanks!

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: See related concept of Kolmogorov complexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: A cultural aside: at the art exhibit "Mathematics: A Beautiful Elsewhere" in Paris I recall they had a computer set up where visitors were instructed play a game of writing numbers minimally like you describe.

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity would be relevant if you allowed an operator like "Output of the C program whose ASCII code is". For the limited list of operators in the question, the issue seems to be more number-theoretic than computability-theoretic.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I see now that I am asking about a specific version of Kolmogorov complexity, under a constrained and limited programming language. It seems that, still, there are issues here concerning the size of the prime factors of a number that do not arise in Kolmogorov complexity...

Comment: Oh, yes, there are certainly issues here; I meant only to suggest that Kolmogorov complexity shares a certain affinity with your question. Like Andreas, I'm not sure exactly how one would use this affinity to answer the question. Joseph, may I ask why you assign zero cost to operations? This is an aspect of your account that differs from Kolmogorov complexity. For example, one might also find it natural to find the smallest term representing a given number in the formal language you have developed (adding a constant for $1$), an approach that would also avoid the dependence on the base.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Good questions! I was thinking of the prime factorization as a means of compression, where, e.g., $8712=2^3 3^2 11^2$, and in our usual arithmetic conventions, the multiplication and exponentiation operators are literally invisible. Which led me to wonder if all operators were invisible/free...

Comment: Every natural can be expressed with a single digit --- and some number of factorial symbols, square root symbols, and floor symbols. So I think you must be more precise about the rules of the game. Maybe the smallest efficiently representable number is $24=4!$. Or maybe $125=5^3$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, it does not make difference (up to a constant factor), because in a binary tree the number of external nodes (leaves) is always equal to one plus the number of internal nodes.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Kolmogorov complexity may be defined relatively to any class of models (not necessary full Turing machines).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, a more accurate reference than "Kolmogorov complexity" is "minimum description length". Computationally, MDL is almost always either "impossible" or "very difficult". However, in most cases it can be well approximated by Bayesian complexity.

Comment: May I ask you what is reason behind the question. If it is, for example, to minimize the ink to write down the numbers one can easily imagine a coding such that each number between 0 and 999 has the same (low) cost... So ?

Comment: @PatrickI-Z: It was more to minimize the size of the numeric nodes in an expression tree, rather than minimizing "ink."

Comment: If you like "base 1", you might consider the one complexity of an integer.  The version I like involves plus, times, parentheses, and as few copies of the number 1 as can be managed.  The one complexity of x is x for x < 6, and goes up as log base 3 x.  An unanswered question is if 4lg3 x is an upper bound for x>1, although it is known 3lg2 x is. (I'm using base 2 and base 3 logs here.)  It turns out to be easy to approximate but hard to determine exactly and quickly for many x.  Gerhard "Has Some Ear Worms, Too" Paseman, 2013.12.02

Answer (score 3):

I think what's wanted are the numbers tabulated at http://oeis.org/A104233, in which case the start of the list is 125, 128, 216, 243, 256, 343, 512, 625, 729, 1000, 1015,  1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1029, 1030, 1031, 1032, 1033. These are perfect powers, or $4^5\pm d$ with $d$ a single digit.

Comment: Nice find! So $\{ /,(,) \}$ never occur in the optimal representation?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I guess that it is easy to prove that $99^{99}/9$ is the optimal representation.

Comment: Also $1029=3\cdot 7^3.$ It may be that $5\cdot 6^3=1080$ is the smallest one not a perfect power nor $a^b \pm c$

Comment: Perhaps $(7^9+9^9)/2$ is an optimal representation using parentheses, but I haven't made any serious effort to check this.

Answer (score 1):

In the limit of large $N$, I'd have thought a simple lower bound for the average "compression ratio" by minimal-length representations in base $b$ is something like $\frac{log(b)}{log(b + n)}$, where $n$ is the number of extra symbols permitted. This is because one can simply identify the symbols with extra digits in base $b + n$, and map the base $b$ numbers to the base $b + n$ numbers, obtaining a conservative estimate by neglecting symbol constraints such as the need for balanced brackets and no trailing $+$ signs etc.